# Showing that the integral is unchanged after translation

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, riemann-integration, multiple-integral

Suppose I have a bounded region $A \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ and $T$ is a translation on $\mathbb{R}^n$. How do I show taht

$$\int_{A} 1 = \int_{T(A)} 1$$

This looks seemingly intuitive, as the area of $A$ is unchanged. However, how do I show it mathematically?

Also I'm dealing with Riemann integrals here.

Comment: You have to use the definition of the integral. This result is immediate once you use the definition.

Comment: @Yanko Did you mean the supremum of the lower sums (or the infimum of the upper sums)? Note that $A4 is not a rectangle. How should I proceed?

Comment: Either would work. The expression you get for the LHS is exactly the same as the expression you get for the RHS.

Comment: @Yanko $A$ is an arbitrary region though. It's not a rectangle. Usually we make a rectangle that includes $A$ and set $f$ to be zero in the region outside of $A$. I'm not sure how to derive what you're suggesting.